Polars.apply() by several columns
I have dataframe Polars with a lot of columns. I need to create new columnt with the result of my own function

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'Stock_name': ['reserve', 'fullfilment', 'ntl', 'ntl'],
    'doc_type': ['sales', 'moving', 'sales', 'corr'],
})


def doc_check(row):
    if (row['Stock_name'] == 'reserve') or (row['Stock_name'] == 'ntl'):
        if row['doc_type'] == 'sales':
            doc = 'sales'
        else:
            doc = row['doc_type']
    else:
        doc = row['doc_type']
    return doc


df = df.apply(doc_check).alias('doc_type_new')
df['doc_type_new'] = df.apply(doc_check)

But I received an error "TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str". Where is an error in my code?

That function is called map_rows now. The docs state: "The frame-level map_rows cannot track column names" and "you should use the expression-level map_elements syntax instead". However, you should implement your function in Polars expressions instead if possible.

You can use pl.struct to extract the two columns and then use map_elements to map over it:
df = df.with_columns(
    doc_type_new=pl.struct("Stock_name", "doc_type").map_elements(
        doc_check, return_dtype=pl.String
    )
)

print(df)

Output:
shape: (4, 3)
┌─────────────┬──────────┬──────────────┐
│ Stock_name  ┆ doc_type ┆ doc_type_new │
│ ---         ┆ ---      ┆ ---          │
│ str         ┆ str      ┆ str          │
╞═════════════╪══════════╪══════════════╡
│ reserve     ┆ sales    ┆ sales        │
│ fullfilment ┆ moving   ┆ moving       │
│ ntl         ┆ sales    ┆ sales        │
│ ntl         ┆ corr     ┆ corr         │
└─────────────┴──────────┴──────────────┘

Note that in this case, your function can be implemented using native polars API which will run much faster:
df = df.with_columns(
    doc_type_new=pl.when(
        pl.col("Stock_name").is_in(["reserve", "ntl"]) & (pl.col("doc_type") == "sales")
    )
    .then(pl.lit("sales"))
    .otherwise(pl.col("doc_type"))
)

print(df)

(Same output.)
